# SASS bug with compilation

Tags: css, sass, compiler-errors, wampserver, node-sass

I'm new in StackOverflow and I'm a beginner in web development thank advance for your comprehension. 
I have problem with SASS 
it tells me well in my terminal that it compiles my code on my main.css but this shows me the result only a few times on my browser (Firefox and I cleaned his caches).
I use the terminal of VSCode (Windows Powershell) I have SASS with node.js and local server with WAMP.
I find it hard to understand my other projects I did not have this problem.
Know what I can do to fix this? 
You can find my code on GitHub and a video to show you the problem.

Thank you and have a good day!

Code of my project on GitHub: https://github.com/ValentinBnmr/Semaine_Inter

Video:https://youtu.be/dV_FcwNwwcY

PS: Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please post your relevant code in your question, or else link directly to the code on Github rather than to the root of your repository?

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) to any third party site.

Comment: @avocadatoria No. A github link is no different than any other and will get this question closed.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check if the value actually changes within the compiled css file. Since your Sass compiler tells you that it compiled everything successfully, it should then be changed within your css file.

It is most likely your browser's cache. Clearing it once has no effect on later reloads as seen in your video. You can set your browser (both Firefox and Chrome) to deactivate Cache while developer tools are open.

Chrome: open DevTools [Ctrl Shift i], open its settings (either hit [F1] or open via DevTools menu), under "Network" check the box at "Disable cache (while DevTools is open)

Firefox: open Web Developer toolbox [Ctrl Shift i], open its settings (same with Chrome), under "Advanced Settings" check the box at "Disable HTTP Cache (when toolbox is open)"

Whenever you load a site with those tools open (as it should be when doing stuff like this) you will never run into cache issues anymore.